# How do I remove the [""] in an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am retrieving multiple arrays from parse and storing them in an array. It is currently working but when I apply the text at `[indexpath.row]` the label is `["cat", "dog"]` instead I want `cat, dog`.

```
 var animal: [[String]] = []
  if let displayIntake = object["Animal"] as? [String]{

                    self.animal.append(displayIntake)
                    print(self.animal)
                    //prints ["cat", "dog"]
                }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: TutorBoxCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BoxCell
    cell.info.text = "\(animal[indexPath.item])"
    //info is a UILabel
    //on the app the label appears ["cat", "dog"] instead I need it to be cat, dog
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `joinWithSeparator` on the array.

It will join the array elements as a String, separated with the String you pass as an argument.

Example:

```
yourArray.joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

gives

> cat, dog

Use this one if it's an array of arrays:

```
yourArray.map { $0.joinWithSeparator(", ") }.joinWithSeparator("")
```

This one means we join each sub-array with ", " then we join everything in a String.

And given the content of the array you showed me in the comments, the right combination for you would be something like this example:

```
let animals = [ ["dog", "cat"], ["chicken", "bat"] ]

let results = animals.map { $0.joinWithSeparator(", ") }

for content in results {
    print(content)
}
```

prints

> dog, cat
>   chicken, bat

And just for the example to be complete:

```
let all = results.joinWithSeparator(" - ")

print(all)
```

prints

> dog, cat - chicken, bat

Comment: I get the error `cannot invoke 'join with separator' with an argument list of type String`

Comment: This error message means you're applying `joinWithSeparator` to a String instead of applying it to an array.

Comment: animal is instantiated as an array though.

Comment: That's not what your compiler seems to think. :) You should debug what is really your value, maybe you think it's an array and it's not. Use `print` or breakpoints to see what your values really are.

Comment: I did and it is indeed printing an array. It's an array of arrays if that makes a difference

Comment: I tried it with `var x = [String]` and it works, seems like it's not working because it's an array within an array.

Comment: I updated my code with what you provided, and it's still not working.

Comment: Then please show me exactly what gives `print(self.animal)` just after `self.animal.append(displayIntake)`. For now I feel blind - my answer should work for you, so something is different from what I/you think. Thanks.

Comment: `[  ["dog", "cat"] ["chicken", "bat"]  ]` and the uilabel looks like `["dog", "cat"] ["chicken", "bat"]`

Comment: Ok, I've made another update. This one should be the right one. :)